# jQuery if statement: section id matches href # within <a>

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Goal:**
prevent the `yes` class being removed from an element if it isn't being added to another.

I have the following code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var position = $(this).scrollTop();

        if ($('#services').length) {
            $('section').each(function() {
                var target = $(this).offset().top;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                //if statement goes here i think?

                if (position >= target - 79) {
                    $('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a').removeClass('yes');
                    $('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a[href*="#' + id + '"]').addClass('yes');
                }
            });
        };
    });

})
```

I'd like to write a nested `if` statement that will trigger `position >= target` if one of the menu items links (`<a href="#~"/>`) is the same as the `id` of any of the `section` elements on the page.

HTML as requested

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <ul class="nav"><li><a href="#home"/></li><li><a href="second"/></li></ul>
</div>
<section id="home"></section>
<section id="an-id-that-isnt-in-the-menu"></section>
<section id="second"></section>
```

Comment: Please share your html.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ see the edit

Comment: there is no yes class to remove in first place

Comment: @SachinDivakar that's intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement should be like this:

```
var selector = ".menu-wrap > ul > li > a[href=#" + id + "]";
if ($(selector).length) {
```

With your JS:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var position = $(this).scrollTop();

        if ($('#services').length) {
            $('section').each(function() {
                var target = $(this).offset().top;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var selector = ".menu-wrap > ul > li > a[href=#" + id + "]";

                if ($(selector).length > 0) {
                    if (position >= target - 79) {
                        $('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a').removeClass('yes');
                        $('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a[href*="#' + id + '"]').addClass('yes');
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it doesn't really do what I was after. To be more explicit, I'd like for one of the `<a/>` elements to ALWAYS have the class `yes`. Here's a link to the script in action: http://hotglue.com.au/x_2013/